# superfish drop-down menu displaying underneath div below it

Tags: html, css, superfish

Example of what it is doing: http://screenr.com/k2X

I set the z-index of div class="container_12 header" to 2 and the div class="container_12 content" to 1

the ul class="sf-menu" is set to 99, which is within the container_12 header div

I've had this problem before and thought setting the z-index's appropriately for classes would do the trick, but it still giving me that problem of displaying the drop-down menu behind the div beneath (container_12 content)

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
.container_12.content {
  z-index: 1;
}

.container_12.header {
  background-color:#030;
  height:125px;
  border:1px solid yellow;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Maybe put the drop-down inside the body element instead of a div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the div where the superfish menu and logout button are has the property `overflow:scroll;`
Change that to `visible`.

```
overflow:visible;
z-index:0;
position:relative;
```

**Note**: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

EDIT: for best results, load **[htmlreset.css](http://ajax.microdual.com/css/htmlreset.css)** before!

Comment: thanks, that did the trick, now in IE 7, the menu seems to be transparent, as you can see here http://cl.ly/2315231db5666d6e3297 - you know why that may be?

Comment: thats the z-index, and position, make sure that all elements are with lower z-index and position:relative.

test with something like this: *{position:relative;z-index:0;} //Before all other CSS styles!

Comment: for best results, load htmlreset.css before

Answer (score 0):

Are your divs and ul positionned ? I think z-index only works on positionned selectors.